# How to download a file using Ext JS library?

Tags: file, extjs, download

I'm a newby in Ext JS and I need to make a restful call that returns a file to the browser. How should I do this?

This is what I have so far, the call is return but I can't get the file downloaded to the browser.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

form = Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/getfile',
    success: function(x){
                 return x; 
                 },
    failure: function () { console.log('failure');},
    params: {'someparams': Ext.encode ({'abc': {'hello': '123'}})
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you can use original javascript:

```
document.location = "/getfile?abc=123";
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?23937-Problem-in-downloading-XLS-file-using-Ext.Ajax.Request....) or [this post](http://particletree.com/notebook/ajax-file-download-or-not/) useful.  Basically don't use AJAX here, use a `<form>` to submit your request